# Where can I ask this question about cellphone early termination and my best options?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My wife's smart phone ( android http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SPH-D700ZKASPR ) charging port is broken, I don't have any insurance on the phone.

The carrier is Sprint, what is my best option? It's been 7 months since using that phone.

I am thinking I should terminate the line and get a new line, but I see that the termination fee for the advanced phones is 350$. So, I am wondering what options do I have?

Where can I ask this question?

Comment: If you have a spare phone laying around, most companies will let you switch out phones on the same contract. They only make you sign new contracts to get the major discounts. If you have a spare or can find a different one for cheap, you can most likely take it in and have them activate that one and deactivate the old one.

Comment: @animuson Thank you! I will try that. I have a spare phone with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go for Android questions.

However, data plans and carrier-specific stuff is off-topic there. So it doesn't look like your question fits on any of the sites in the Stack Exchange network.

> So, I am wondering what options do I have?

It sounds like this is a question that you should ask your cell phone carrier. Their customer service line is there to, well, service the customer (or at least to sell them things, and you're in the market to buy).